# Visual Studio 2017 Intellisense with HTML in reactjs .js file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense

If I create a brand new React.js project in Visual Studio 2017 using the menu options:

> File -> New Project -> ASP.NET Core Web Application -> React.js

And I simply navigate to the generated file  `\ClientApp\src\components\Home.js` and attempt to edit the `render()` html, I get a lesser version html intellisense within that .js file.  This file being a .js file I assume is the problem.  How can I make things such as auto closing html tags happen?  It is aware of html elements, but it does NOT create the closing tag for me which happens in the html files.

Is this possible?